# There's no [mootools] tag here yet

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I've just joined Code Review and am looking around I didn't find the [mootools](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mootools) tag.

Could someone please create the [mootools](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mootools)?  I don't have enough rep and I think it deserves its place on Code Review.

Comment: Which question(s) should receive this new tag?

Comment: @Jamal, this for example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/clean-up-if-or-syntax-in-javascript-mootools

Comment: Done.  I'll retag any other related questions (mostly unanswered).

Comment: @Jamal, thank you!

Comment: No problem.  You may suggest the wiki excerpts if you'd like.

Comment: @Jamal, just did. Copied the Stackoverflow's which is very complete. Should be in the review queue now :)

Comment: Alright.  Welcome to CR!

Comment: Update: check your suggestion status.  There was a reject because of some SO-related aspects left intact (such as taking non-working code, which CR does not do).

Comment: @Jamal, thank you. I just suggested a edit to be more correct to CR